# Movimiento que hace el toro con su pata

Tags: solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, palabras-raras, animales

¿Cuál es la palabra que significa el movimiento que hace el toro con su pata trasera cuando quiere atacar o embestir? Recuerdo vagamente haberla leído con anterioridad pero no recuerdo donde.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Al movimiento con la pata delantera parece ser que se le llama "escarbar". Dejo aquí un par de diccionarios de tauromaquia. No he encontrado nada relativo a un movimiento de la pata **trasera**. [clubtaurinobilbao](http://www.clubtaurinobilbao.com/movimientos-ofensivos-y-defensivos-del-toro/), [diccionario taurino](http://www.ganaderoslidia.com/webroot/diccionario.htm)

Comment: @Diego de hecho en el DLE también lo comentan en la entrada de [_escarbar_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GB6sTXD): Rayar o remover repetidamente la superficie de la tierra, ahondando algo en ella, según suelen hacerlo con las patas el toro, el caballo, la gallina, etc.

Comment: No creo que el OP esté pensando en **piafar** que es "Dicho de un caballo, ‘alzar las patas delanteras dejándolas caer con fuerza’"

Answer (score 1):

No sé si esto es lo que buscas, pero lo que yo he oído para esta acción es

**[patear](https://dle.rae.es/?id=S8RofSS)**

> 7. intr. coloq. Dar patadas en el suelo en señal de enojo, dolor o desagrado. (DRAE)

Answer (score 1):

En el léxico taurino, se llama un *desafío*:<sup>[1](http://www.ganaderoslidia.com/webroot/diccionario.htm#D) [2](https://www.madrid-traveller.com/bullfighting-terms/)</sup>

> **DESAFIAR** - Acción del toro en la que, parándose y fijándose en los bultos escarba la arena, cabecea, se  encampana, y luego se humilla, tapándose y juntando el hocico con el suelo.
>
> - [*Glosario de términos taurinos*](http://www.joseluisabascal.com/libros/Glosario%2520de%2520t%25C3%25A9rminos%2520taurinos.pdf)

---

<sup>Más generalmente, además de las sugerencias de Diego (*escarbar*), Patricio (*piafar*) y aparente001, hay:</sup>

> <sup>[**patalear**](https://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=patalear)</sup>  
>  <sup>2. intr. Dar patadas en el suelo violentamente y con prisa por enfado o pesar.</sup>